# „Undefined Control sequence“ when changing to „et al“

Tags: biblatex, rmarkdown, bookdown

I‘m very new to latex and try to write my bachelor thesis with Rmarkdown and tinytex (and got a Template from my Professor).
My problem is, that I can‘t change the german u.a. To the latin „et al.“ in my bibliography. I tried `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}` in my preamble, but it fails to compile with the error „ ! Undefined control sequence.“

Thank you in advance!

Edit: My YAML-Header Looks like this

```
---
geometry: "a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3.5cm,right=2cm"
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
automark: yes
indent: true
toc: false
classoption:
  - DIV=calc
  - headsepline=true
KOMAoptions:
  - headings=standardclasses
  - DIV=last  
table_caption: true
figure_caption: true
includes:  
  in_header: figure_placement.tex 
link-citations: yes
knit: "bookdown::render_book"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: tex/praeambel.tex
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: bib/literatur.bib
biblio-style: authoryear
---
```

My preamble is looking like this:

```
%% Preamble
%%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   VARIOUS REQUIRED PACKAGES AND CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



\usepackage{graphicx} % Include graphics
\graphicspath{{img/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,setspace} % Using nice book tables etc.
\usepackage{tabularx} % Better package to handle and create complex tables
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\usepackage{rotating}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Fonts and German language and other stuff for data exploration
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Symbol, Chancery and Computer Modern fonts
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel} % German language and other
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Used font -> some argue you should use Xelatex... pdflatex is here the prefered engine! (Mac, Linux, Win)
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} % Using german package for quotes
\usepackage{textcomp} % Package with lots of symbols  
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc} % Control and customize footnotes
\usepackage[justification=centering, format=hang]{caption} % Package offers customization of captions in floating environments 
\usepackage{ragged2e} % This package provides new commands and environments for setting ragged text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Customize the page header and footer in an easy way
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % Include appendix to your document
\usepackage{eurosym} % The European currency symbol for the Euro implemented in METAFONT
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym} % This package ensures that all acronyms used in the text are spelled out in full at least once
\usepackage{blindtext} % You are always wasting time with reading a blindtext 
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Definitions for the whole project
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Defining the rule above and under the title
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 

% Long quotes in singlespace and small for markdown / pandoc
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\singlespacing\small} 

%% Acronym für Abbildung
\addto\captionsngerman{
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}}

% Defining color
\definecolor{buw}{RGB}{230,243,205}

% et al. anstatt u.a.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
```

Comment: The command `\DefineBibliographyStrings` is a `biblatex` command. But the rest of the code you have shown so far does not load `biblatex` at all. For all we know it might be using a different bibliography/citation package (presumably a BibTeX-based approach: note the absence of the `la` in that name). In that case `\DefineBibliographyStrings` would simply not be the right command. What would be the right command would depend on code not shown so far.

Comment: I edited my question. Now you can see  that I defined biblatex as bibliography. It functions as well, because my bibliography is shown with the „authoryear“ style

Comment: In that case this might be a timing issue which you might be able to solve with `\AtEndPreamble{\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}}`

Comment: That worked! Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

With Rmarkdown timing can be important. Packages that are loaded via options in the YAML file may or may not be available when the preamble file is processed. In this case it helps to wrap the `biblatex` commands in an `\AtEndPremable`, so that they are executed when `biblatex` has been loaded.

Replace the `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}` with

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}%
}
```